# Trash is empty, but the trash bin icon looks like there is something in it

Tags: unity, trash

[image]

My trash is empty, but the trash bin icon has some screwed up paper in it, as if there is something there.

Comment: Maybe there are hidden files in it, which are not deleted?! Try hitting `ctrl+h`and empty it again.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem was I simply deleted another useless file and emptied the Trash again.